# Drawing directed graph in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

My goal is to draw the following graph:
[image]
I tried to write the code with the package TikZ, but the final graph was as follows:
[image]
Its code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{dot/.style = 
{circle,
draw=blue,
line width=.5pt},
dot/.default = 4pt
}

\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Axes
%\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-7, -7) grid (7, 7);
%\draw[->,ultra thick] (-7,0)--(7,0) node[right]{$x$};
%\draw[->,ultra thick] (0, -7)--(0, 7) node[above]{$y$};

  % First, define nodes
  \draw (-5, 0) node[
                            circle,
                            inner sep=0pt,
                            fill=black,
                            label={left:{$A$}}
                            ] (A) {};  
  \draw (-2, 2) node[
                            circle,
                            inner sep=0pt,
                            fill=black,
                            label={above:{$B$}}
                            ] (B) {};  
  \draw (2, 2) node (C) {$C$}; 
  \draw (5, 0) node (D) {$D$}; 
  \draw (2, -2) node (E) {$E$}; 
  \draw (-2, -2) node (F) {$F$};  

  % Draw curved path
  \path [thick, draw=black, postaction={very thick, on each segment={mid arrow=black}}]
  (A) to [bend left] (B)
  (A) to [bend right] (B)
  (B) to [bend left] (C)
  (B) to [bend right] (C)
  (C) to [bend left] (D)
  (C) to [bend right] (D)
  (E) to [bend left] (D)
  (E) to [bend right] (D)
  (E) to (D)
  (F) to [bend left] (E)
  (F) to [bend right] (E)
  (F) to (E)
  (A) to [bend left] (F)
  (A) to [bend right] (F)
  (A) to (F);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to change it to draw the figure above?

Comment: Why are you using a coordinate for A and B (which you label with a node) and a node for the rest? That is (partly) the reason why your figure looks different than your intended picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really no reason to overcomplicate things.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate, decoration={
markings,
mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}}
}}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=2pt, circle] (A) at (-5,0) {$A$};
\node[inner sep=2pt, circle] (B) at (-2,2) {$B$};
\node[inner sep=2pt, circle] (C) at (2,2) {$C$}; 
\node[inner sep=2pt, circle] (D) at (5,0) {$D$}; 
\node[inner sep=2pt, circle] (E) at (2,-2) {$E$}; 
\node[inner sep=2pt, circle] (F) at (-2,-2) {$F$};  

\draw[thick, mid arrow] (A.north east) to[bend left] (B.south west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (A.north east) to[bend right] (B.south west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (B.east) to[bend left] (C.west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (B.east) to[bend right] (C.west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (C.east) to[bend left] (D.north west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (C.east) to[bend right] (D.north west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (A.south east) to[bend left] (F.north west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (A.south east) to[bend right] (F.north west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (A.south east) to (F.north west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (F.east) to[bend left] (E.west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (F.east) to[bend right] (E.west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (F.east) to (E.west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (E.east) to[bend left] (D.south west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (E.east) to[bend right] (D.south west);
\draw[thick, mid arrow] (E.east) to (D.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nodes in a circle with bend arrows]

Answer (score 4):

Just name the nodes with the letters inside them and don't use coordinates with labels, then you can use each node (with its name) as part of a connection `(A) -- (B)` and TikZ finds the points on their borders on its own.
It does the same for `bend left` and `bend right` but uses other points on the border than the straight part.

But with a normal (undrawn) `--` path you can find easily the points on the nodes' borders and save them. (We could also calculate angles or just specify the anchors manually, of course).

I give the first node an alias `G` so that it can simply be accessed in a loop.

The LaTeX function `\@Alph` helps to turn a number (`\cnt`) into a letter. We could also use numbers instead of letters to name the nodes which would make this a bit easier. For more than 26 nodes, you will need another way to name your nodes.

I'm using the uptodate [`arrows.meta` library](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#section-arrows-meta) and its `Stealth` arrow which doesn't need additional scaling. If you want another arrow you can choose the one you want, the library offers plenty tip styles.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{% style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{Stealth}}}}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\intToChar[1]{\@Alph{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axes
%\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-7, -7) grid (7, 7);
%\draw[->,ultra thick] (-7,0)--(7,0) node[right]{$x$};
%\draw[->,ultra thick] (0, -7)--(0, 7) node[above]{$y$};

% First define nodes
\foreach[count=\cnt] \pnt/\lab in {(-5, 0)/A,
                                   (-2, 2)/B,
                                   ( 2, 2)/C,
                                   ( 5, 0)/D,
                                   ( 2,-2)/E,
                                   (-2,-2)/F}
  \node (\lab) at \pnt {$\lab$};
\path node also [alias=G] (A);

% Find points on their border to the other nodes
\foreach \lab[count=\cnt from 2] in {A, ..., F}
  \path (\lab) -- coordinate[at start] (\lab-to-\intToChar{\cnt})
                  coordinate[at end]   (\intToChar{\cnt}-to-\lab)
                  (\intToChar{\cnt});

% Draw the lines and curves
\path [thick, every edge/.append style={mid arrow}]
  foreach \A/\B in {A/B, B/C, C/D, G/F, F/E, E/D} {
   (\A-to-\B) edge [bend left] (\B-to-\A)
              edge [bend right] (\B-to-\A)
  }
  foreach \A/\B in {G/F, F/E, E/D} {
    (\A) edge (\B)
  }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]